# onClick not called in extended Layout

Tags: android

Why is the onClickListener not getting called in my extended `LinearLayout`? When i include `Setting_1` in my activity's layout, the onClick does not trigger.

Here is the layout of the compound control :

**setting.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the abstract class that uses the above layout :

**IntegerSettingLayout.java**

```
public abstract class IntegerSettingLayout extends LinearLayout implements
        OnClickListener {

    public IntegerSettingLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting, this, true);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    //this is not getting called
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onClick");}
    }

    abstract String getStatus();
    ...
}
```

Here is the class that implements the above abstract class

**Setting_1.java**

```
public class setting_1 extends IntegerSettingLayout{

    public Setting_WeekFrequency(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ...

    }

    @Override
    String getStatus() {
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {Log.d(LOG_TAG,"getStatus");}
    }

}
```

Comment: `onClick` is a Listener, you have to trigger that so it will work, You do that either by calling a method with`onClick=""` from Xml or by referencing view id in `onClick()` method of your activity.
Or if you want to trigger that without clicking any view you just call `getActivity.setClickable(true);` to your constructor.

Comment: @hrskrs i did `implements OnClickListener`. So `onClick` is expected to work?

Comment: Yeah but because you implemented you have to trigger that `yourView.setOnClickListener(this);` and `onClick()` method you can use a `switch{ case: R.id.yourViewId }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually registered your `OnClickListener`. You need to call `setOnClickListener()` for that, or use `android:onClick` attribute in XML.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to use `implements OnClickListener` while extending the Layout class?

Comment: thanks you are right. i had to do `setOnClickListener(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `this.setClickable(true);` to your constructor.

Comment: it made no difference